# numpy: complex row by column img part is zero

Tags: python, c, numpy

I have a row and a column `(1, 3)` and  `(3,1)`
with these values

```
a = np.array([[-0.000147028898936696350574+0.003143749432638287544250j,
               -0.000184992561116814613342+0.001760595943778753280640j,
               -0.000147028898936696350574+0.003143749432638287544250j]], dtype=np.complex64)
b = np.array([[-147.028900146484375000000000-3143.749511718750000000000000j],
              [-184.992553710937500000000000-1760.595947265625000000000000j],
              [-147.028900146484375000000000-3143.749511718750000000000000j]], dtype=np.complex64)
```

I want to multiply the two

```
c = np.matmul(a, b, dtype=np.complex64)
print (c)
```

setting print options like this

```
np.seterr(all='raise')
np.set_printoptions(precision=24)
np.set_printoptions(floatmode="fixed")
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
```

I get

```
>>> print (c)
[[22.943477630615234375000000+0.000000000000000000000000j]]
```

If I do the multiplication manually like

```
d = a[0][0]*b[0][0] + a[0][1]*b[1][0] + a[0][2]*b[2][0]
```

I get

```
print (d)
(22.943478+5.9604645e-08j
```

that is consistent with a matching C example

```
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  complex float a[] = { -0.000147028898936696350574+0.003143749432638287544250*I, 
    -0.000184992561116814613342+0.001760595943778753280640*I,
    -0.000147028898936696350574+0.003143749432638287544250*I};

  complex float b[] = {-147.028900146484375000000000-3143.749511718750000000000000*I,
    -184.992553710937500000000000-1760.595947265625000000000000*I,
    -147.028900146484375000000000-3143.749511718750000000000000*I };

  complex float  den  = a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1] +  a[2] * b[2];

  printf("%+.30e  %+.30ej\n", crealf(den), cimagf(den) );
  return 0;
}
```

```
x@y:~$ gcc main.c && ./a.out 
+2.294347763061523437500000000000e+01  +5.960464477539062500000000000000e-08j
```

I as shown the real part matches but the imaginary does not, why?

Comment: I guess that the problem is due to floating point precision. Numpy use some highly optimized algorithm to compute a matrix multiplication so it is hard to compare your `C` code and the `python` one. But if you use the trivial `np.sum(a*b.T)` you obtain (almost) the same result as your `C` code.

Comment: @obchardon if I do ```d = a[0][0]*b[0][0] + a[0][1]*b[1][0] + a[0][2]*b[2][0] print (d)``` I get the ```>>> print (d)
(22.943478+5.9604645e-08j)
``` but still `0.000000000000000000000000j` is very different from 5.9604645e-08j

Comment: Something to note is that `complex64` is not a complex value where each part is `float64` (which is what I initially assumed), its total size is 64-bit, so its composed of two `float32`. You've only got 23 bits of fraction, so your "detail" between numbers that you add must be much larger than ~1/8,000,000 of the size of the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be with precisions. When computing complex64 numbers numpy somehow rounds up the result to 0. If you use `dtype=complex128` or `dtype=complex256`, the imaginary part is different from 0. But multiplying the numbers you have provided gives me different imaginary part:

```
a = np.array([[-0.000147028898936696350574+0.003143749432638287544250j,
           -0.000184992561116814613342+0.001760595943778753280640j,
           -0.000147028898936696350574+0.003143749432638287544250j]], 
dtype=np.complex256)
b = np.array([[-147.028900146484375000000000-3143.749511718750000000000000j],
          [-184.992553710937500000000000-1760.595947265625000000000000j],
          [-147.028900146484375000000000-3143.749511718750000000000000j]], dtype=np.complex256)
np.matmul(a, b)
array([[22.94347681+2.93314883e-08j]], dtype=complex256)
```

**UPDATE**:
The difference in your C code output and my python is due to precisions again, if you use `double` values in your C code, then the output will be identical to mine.